# Drag and Drop Java Script Executor returns undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm testing a drag and drop feature on a web application using Selenium, and I am using a java script to carry out the dragging and dropping functionality

I have a fair understanding on the function but I am not able to wrap my head around its complete working

I am souring the web elements using Selenium's findElement method

```
    WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#todrag > span:nth-child(4)"));
    WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mydropzone"));
```

and the below is where the action takes place

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) { var event = document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\"); event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null); event.dataTransfer = { data: {}, setData: function (key, value) { this.data[key] = value; }, getData: function (key) { return this.data[key]; } }; return event; } function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) { if (transferData !== undefined) { event.dataTransfer = transferData; } if (element.dispatchEvent) { element.dispatchEvent(event); } else if (element.fireEvent) { element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event); } } function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) { var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart'); dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent); var dropEvent = createEvent('drop'); dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer); var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend'); dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer); } var elementToDrag = arguments[0]; var target = arguments[1]; simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(elementToDrag, target);",
                From, To);
```

This code seems to work perfectly fine on `"https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop"` but fails to work on `"https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html"`

The below is the error I see on the screen

[image]

It'd be great if someone helps me understand and resolve this issue

The site's JS can be found in this link - https://easyupload.io/dgefbv